# Em quantas threads devo dividir uma tarefa?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C#, uma das minhas funções pode ser executada com múltiplas threads. Porém, quantas devo utilizar? Se o processador possui 4 núcleos, há vantagem em se utilizar mais de 4 threads?

Comment: Você precisa dar mais detalhes do que sua função faz

Answer (score 2):

Os núcleos/cores não estão relacionados diretamente com "suas Threads", nem quer dizer que se você usar *4 threads* ele vai ser executado cada um em um núcleo diferente, quem gerencia isso é o *sistema operacional* e não a sua aplicação *"a principio"* (veja `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`).

O motivo dos processadores modernos terem mais de um núcleo não é **pra você** tornar o seu programa especificamente mais rápido, é para que que o sistema operacional consiga gerenciar os programas em geral.

**Respondendo (independente da pergunta sobre núcleos):**

> Se o processador possui 4 núcleos, há vantagem em se utilizar mais de 4 threads?

Não para o processador e pela explicação acima, agora esquecendo sobre núcleos e afins, `4 threads` ou menos ou mais terá vantagem se você e o seu programa tiverem a necessidade de isolar uma tarefa, se não tiver motivos para fazer isso no contexto do seu programa não tem vantagem alguma e nem o porque de fazer isto. Claro que muitas coisas podem ser feitas de várias maneiras, mas isto é uma estratégia própria sua que vai depender do que você esta fazendo.

> Porém, quantas devo utilizar?

Vai depender da necessidade, criar múltiplas threads sem necessidade também vai acarretar custos para a máquina em questão de performance, como disse antes, depende da necessidade e talvez da estratégia que deseja aplicar isto.

---

### Sobre ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads

Note que o método [**`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) pode limitar o numero de Threads por núcleo no entanto é necessário checar o limite **minimo** que pode ser usado [**`GetMinThreads`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads(v=vs.110).aspx). Mas não quer dizer que você terá um controle absoluto sobre isto ou que terá alguma vantagem só por usar isto *gratuitamente*, ou seja, pode ser que ajude ou pode ser que ocorra ao contrário, piore as coisas.

Mas não dá para afirmar nada sem efetuar seus próprios testes para sua aplicação especifica.